# Exiting `ifup` when waiting for master bond0 to be ready

Tags: networking, server, network-bonding

I'm working on teaming to NIC using `bond-mode 6`, although during my restart process for the NIC's (which must be out of order), I ran the command `sudo ifup etho0` and received the message `Waiting for bond master bond0 to be ready`. That part I understand, I must have messed the order of which interfaces need to be brought up, which is my second question: What oder should I bring up the interfaces?

My primary question though is, how do I cancel or exit waiting for `bond0` to be ready? I tried `CTRL + C` (`^C`) with no resolve. Please see the screenshot below.

This is using `ifenslave-2.6` on ubuntu server 14.04.2

[image]

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` config

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-primary eth0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
bond-mode 6
bond-miimon 100
bond-lacp-rate 1
bond-slaves eth0 eth1
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Suspend the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. You'll return to the shell prompt.
2. Kill the suspended process in the background. To send `SIGKILL` to the first shell job (`%1`), run:

   ```
   kill -s KILL %1
   ```

   If the stalled process is not the first job, run `jobs` to find it and replace `1` with the appropriate job ID.

Comment: Good one!  Upvoted!  ;-)

Comment: I've just tried this, and nothing seems to work.... my ifup is just keeps doing dhcp discovery.... using Ubuntu Server LTS 16

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.